# Dl4j or word2vec which one is better from the aspect of accuracy?

Tags: java, word2vec

I want to convert words into vectors and I have found that word2vec and dl4j based on nueral networks are  better way for doing that. I am interested in java. I want to ask that which one is better dl4j or word2vec?

Comment: That probably depends on the use case. This question smells very much opinion-based and as such off-topic.

Comment: I want ask from the accuracy point of view.

Comment: Word2vec is a neural network. Deeplearning4j is an open-source neural net framework for the JVM. It includes an implementation of Word2vec, which is just like all the others: http://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec.html  The feature vectors obtained with word2vec can be fed to other neural networks...

Comment: Thanks, actually I want to use word2vec for doing sentiment analysis. Can you provide any tutorial to help me with  implementation